# Learning MIPS assembly

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm taking a look at assembly and the MIPS instruction set. Here is my basic first program that I'm studying:

```
.text
    .globl main
main:
    li  $t0, -10 #  $t0 = -10   ("load immediate")
    li  $t1, -31 #  $t1 = -31   ("load immediate")
    li  $t2, -10 #  $t2 = -10   ("load immediate")
    li  $t3, -31 #  $t3 = -31   ("load immediate")

    #swap

    xor $t0, $t0, $t1
    xor $t1, $t0, $t1
    xor $t0, $t0, $t1

    addu    $t2, $t2, $t3
    subu    $t3, $t2, $t3
    subu    $t2, $t2, $t3

    li  $v0, 10
    syscall
```

Now I want to understand what each instruction does as I can run this program in my emulator which makes me wonder more about this program and what it does and how I might change it to learn more assembly. Could you for starters tell me how to comment the xor, addu and subu parts, and what does syscall mean and the very first part .text and .blobl main?

Am I making this more difficult than it really is? You may also please provide me with tutorials to MIPS assembly programming.

Comment: You should look for MIPS instruction set and decode it yourself. `syscall` is used for calling system call for printing output and getting input: the specific instruction is read from `$v0`. http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/Help/SyscallHelp.html

Comment: OK, thanks for the comment. I'm sorta wondering why the instruction is `li`and now `lw` or similar and I'm sure that will show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll break that down:

`li` is a so called pseudo instruction, the assembler will split it into `lui` (Load Upper Immediate) and `ori` (OR Immediate), to construct a 32bit value from 2 16bit immediates. While `lw` could be used it usually provides no benefits and trashes a cacheline.

The `xor` will just calculate op1 = op2 XOR op3. In your special case it us used for [Register Swapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm) on $t0 and $t1.

`addu` and `subu` will just add/substract op2 and op3 and store the result into op1. Again, whats shown in your code will swap the two registers $t2 and $t3.

`syscall` will trap into your operating system and execute some specific function. The function number will be stored in $v0, so your example runs function number 10, which seems to be common for "exit".